# SVG pattern in symbol

Tags: svg, symbols

I have a problem with my svg. I want to create a symbol which groups a polygon (here a hexagon) and its background image (as a pattern):

```
    <symbol id="tile" viewBox="0 0 240 208">
        <defs>
            <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="240" height="208">
                <image xlink:href="ground.png" x="0" y="0" width="240" height="208" />
            </pattern>
        </defs>
        <polygon class="tile" fill="url(#img1)" 
                points="60 0, 180 0, 240 104, 180 208, 60 208, 0 104" />
    </symbol>
```

I include the symbol via the `<use>` tag. The problem is that the background image `ground.png` is not visible (the hexagon is filled black instead).

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** http://jsfiddle.net/wuR3G/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong. Your testcase works in Opera. Firefox has an existing bug about `<defs>` within `<symbol>` so you'd have to restructure your example like this for it:

```
<svg width="600" height="624" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 600 624">
    <script type="text/ecmascript" xlink:href="svg.js" />
    <title>Base</title>
    <desc>Hexagon base maptile</desc>
    <defs>
        <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="240" height="208">
            <image xlink:href="https://www.google.de/images/srpr/logo3w.png" x="0" y="0" width="240" height="208" />
        </pattern>
        <symbol id="tile" viewBox="0 0 240 208">
            <polygon class="tile" fill="url(#img1)"
                    points="60 0, 180 0, 240 104, 180 208, 60 208, 0 104" />
        </symbol>
    </defs>
    <use xlink:href="#tile" x="0" y="0" width="240" height="208" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Here is a related bug report: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=353575 (btw. Reported: 2006-09-20 16:01 ... oh my). Chromium has the same bug.